# copy first n chars to an std::string

Tags: c++

I have a char pointer that points to a buffer of unknown length:

```
char* buffer;
```

I need to copy the first N (N is an input variable) chars to an std::string if N !=0.
My current code is:

```
int N = <something>;
std::string text;
if (N != 0)
    text.assign(buffer, N);
else
    text.assign(buffer);
```

the thing I do not like, is that when the size of buffer is less than N, the resulting size of text is N.

Is there any function in the standard library to copy the first N chars of buffer to text without forcing the size of text to N?

i.e if buffer is only 1 char and N = 100, I want that text.size() = 1

Is a custom copy, byte by byte, the solution?

Comment: If you're using C++ it's better to work with `std::string` and the associated methods and operators

Comment: If you need to know the length of a string, fundamental laws of physics of our shared universe require scanning the string until the terminating `'\0` byte is found. There are no shortcuts around that.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik  I do not need to know the length of the buffer. I only need to copy the fist N chars.

Comment: @GovindParmar I am using C and C++ because the code connect a C software with a C++ software

Comment: But you've clearly explained that you do need to know the length of the string, in order to do this correctly. That pretty much seals the deal.

Comment: How could you know the size of `buffer` without traversing it? Presumably it is null-terminated?

Comment: @sam I think you're overlooking a valid use case. You have a null-terminated string of unknown length, and you only want the first `n` chars. Why should you have to copy the entire string just to possibly discard a large number of chars?  `strncpy_s` can do it, why can't `basic_string`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`memchr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memchr) to look for the zero byte, and limit the search to N bytes:

```
size_t N = ...;
char* pos = memchr(buffer, '\0', N);
text.assign(buffer, pos ? pos - buffer : N);
```

If the byte is not found, the length of the output string should be N. If it's found, then `memstr` returns the pointer to it. Subtracting the original pointer will yield the desired length.

This doesn't handle the case of N = 0 in any special manner - that is, if N is 0, the output will be empty. If you want other behavior, make a special-case for it.